# Can you add memory to the new 2017 iMacs that Apple announced on 5 June 2017?

Tags: imac, upgrade, memory

I know that earlier iMacs could be end-user upgraded to add more memory.  I was wondering if that is still the case with the models they announced yesterday, both for the 21" and the 27".

Answer (score 1):

The technical Specs mentioned for the 21" Model no manual accessible Memory, contrary to the 27" Model, see https://www.apple.com/uk/imac/specs/

You can Upgrade the Memory yourself only for the 27" Model, the 21" is onboard Memory (Build-to-Order).